# Android Custom Tab - Text Scrolling

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I am trying to implement a custom TabHost with colored tabs.  I've been following stackoverflow member Josh Clemm's [excellent example](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136).  The coloring works great.  In the default out of the box TabHost, if the text to be displayed in the tab doesn't fit it, it does this nice scrolling of the text inside the tab itself.  It only does this on the active tab and seems to be on a timer where it will pause and the rescroll the text a few times.

Now with the custom tabs I've lost that.  Has anyone else run into this and solved this problem already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:ellipsize="marquee"` and related attributes on your `TextView`.

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` probably needs to be set as well

Comment: Thanks!  I was missing that and the singleLine="true"